# jQuery indexOf is not working properly

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-table, indexof

I ran in to this problem, and can't figure out what to do.

I have table:

```
<table class="jtable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>agea</td>
        <td>haeh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And I need to check first column, this is what I do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = new Array(2, 1);
    $('.jtable').find("tbody tr").each(function(){
        var firstCol = $(this).find("td:first").text();
        var inArray = arr.indexOf(firstCol);
        alert(firstCol+" "+inArray);
        if(inArray == -1){
            $(this).css("background", "red");
        } else {
            $(this).css("background", "green");
        }
    });
});
```

But all I get is -1 for all loop cycles from `indexOf`, when I change `indexOf(firstCol)` to one of the numbers in array it works good, but I need dynamic var there. Any Solutions to this, or what I am doing wrong?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raa8B/

I tried this with `$.inArray` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a string in an integer array. You should convert to an int before `indexOf`

```
 var inArray = arr.indexOf(parseInt(firstCol));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raa8B/1/)

Answer (score 0):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uAmJt/).

You have to cast your `text()` to an integer to compare it with the integers in your array:

```
var firstCol = parseInt($(this).find("td:first").text());
```